# Mapbox won't display town names when there are too many markers

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

On a site I'm working on, a Mapbox map has a lot of markers on it. Because there are so many, it obscures town names. Even when you zoom in, the town name won't appear although landmarks that contain the town's name do.

According to https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/optimize-map-label-placement/ there are some properties to prevent label collision but our code already has those in place.

The map is included as a Vue component which looks like this:

```
    <product-map
            mapstyle=""
            :longitude="145.2814504"
            :latitude="-37.6574789"
            :maxzoom="15"
            :minzoom="9"
            :zoom="10"
            :products="[…]"
            :categories="[…]"
            :settings="{
                    'map': {
                            'cluster':false,
                            'clusterMaxZoom':13
                    },
                    'flyTo':{
                            'zoom':15,
                            'pitch':60,
                            'bearing':45
                    },
                    'marker': {
                            'icon-size':0.844444,
                            'icon-anchor':'center'
                    },
                    'cluster': {
                            'paint': {
                                    'circle-color': [
                                            'step',
                                            ['get','point_count'],
                                            '#15B9CF',
                                            10,
                                            '#15B9CF'
                                    ],
                                    'circle-radius':[
                                            'step',
                                            ['get','point_count'],
                                            25,
                                            10,
                                            35
                                    ],
                                    'circle-stroke-color':'rgba(81, 187, 214, 0.2)',
                                    'circle-stroke-width':25
                            }
                    },
                    'clusterCount':{
                            'layout':{
                                    'text-field':'{point_count_abbreviated}',
                                    'text-font':[],
                                    'text-size':13,
                                    'icon-allow-overlap':true,
                                    'text-allow-overlap':true,
                                    'text-optional':true,
                                    'icon-ignore-placement':true
                            },
                            'paint':{'text-color':'#fff'}
                    }
            }"
    />
```

Is there anything else that can be done?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: @SteveBennett not sure how I can describe it in a way different from what I already have. If a town has a lot of markers for features/attractions within its boundaries, the town name doesn't show, even when you zoom in. As you zoom in, you can see features that contain the town's name, e.g. Placename General Hospital, but not the town name itself. Places that don't have a lot of markers show on the map at the initial zoom level.

Comment: Yes, I understand the current situation. What I don't understand is what you want *instead* of the situation.

Comment: @SteveBennett for the place names to display, at least when the map is zoomed in.

Comment: You're not providing enough detail here. What you refer to as "the map's configuration" looks like part of the description of a single layer in a Mapbox GL style. A runnable demo, like CodePen, or some screenshots would help greatly.

Comment: @SteveBennett I've added some more detail.

Comment: The code you've included is some kind of intermediate component, not the bit which actually calls Mapbox GL JS. You should include a Codepen or similar so people can actually see your code in action.